# ResourceMap в java

Tags: java, загрузка

В интернете не нашел ни описания, ни документации этой функции. Что она делает? И есть ли другие аналоги ResourceMap? Например, я где то слышал что он может загружать ресурсы, но не может прыгнуть на папку выше. Вы бы советовали с ним работать для загрузки ресурсов или есть аналоги получше? И какие варианты есть, если я хочу загрузить ресурсы из файлов *.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет о некотором файле .properties лежащем в директории src > main > resources, скажем config.properties с некоторым содержимым вроде:

```
key=value
```

Можно использовать [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

```
InputStream is = 
    Thread.currentThread()
          .getContextClassLoader()
          .getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(is);
String key = prop.getProperty("key")
```

Еще вариант используя [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html):

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");
String key = rb.getString("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы ее не нашли потомучто такой функции в java core нет.
Для загрузки ресурсов используется

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/resource.xml");
```

или

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resource);
```

вобще варианты разные есть.

Comment: Не могли бы дополнить, какие варианты самые эффективные и удобные при загрузке ресурсов с чтением из файлов *.properties.